# Angularjs and qunit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, qunit

I have a angularjs web application and want to use qunit for unit testing in it. I have a controller:

```
    function RootCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location) {
        // logger is empty at the start
        $scope.logger = '';
        // we have no login error at the start
        $scope.login_error = '';

        //
        // Get values array of object
        //
        $rootScope.values = function (obj) {
            var vals = [];
            for( var key in obj ) {
                if(key !== '$$hashKey' && key !== 'checked')
                    vals.push(obj[key]);
            }
            return vals;
        }
    }
```

Now i want to write unit test for `values` function with `qunit`. I included all `js` files to the `test/index.html` and `qunit.css`. Now my `test.js` has following content:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);

var init = {
    setup : function () {
        this.$scope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    }
}

module('RootCtrl', init);

test('RootCtrl', function(){

    var $controller = injector.get('$controller');

    $controller('RootCtrl', {
            $scope : this.$scope,
        $location : this.$location
    });

    equal(['value'], $controller.values({'key' : 'value'}))

});
```

But i'm getting error: http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$rootElementProvider%20%3C-%20$rootElement%20%3C-%20$location%20%3C-%20$route at:

```
$controller('RootCtrl', {
            $scope : this.$scope,
        $location : this.$location
    });
```

How to inject correctly controller and use `$scope`, `$rootScope`, `$location` and another services from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your controller

```
$controller('RootCtrl',['$scope',  '$rootScope', '$location','$route', function ($scope,  $rootScope, $location,  $route)  {
             $scope : this.$scope,
             $location : this.$location
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, so since no other answer here.

I ended up using:

**client side code:**

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    //angular client side code

    $scope.canSubmit = function () {
        //some logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Qunit tests:**

```
var ctrl, ctrlScope, injector;

module("Testing the controller", {
    setup: function () {
        angular.module('myApp');
        injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);

        ctrlScope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        ctrl = injector.get('$controller')('myCtrl', { $scope: ctrlScope });

        ctrlScope.model = {
            //model object
        };
    },
    teardown: function () {

    }
});

test("Given something happened then allow submit", function () {
    ok(ctrlScope.someFunction(...), "some functionality happened");
    equal(true, ctrlScope.canSubmit());
});
```

[This blog post](http://www.pittrap.com/angularjs-testing-qunit/) was useful.

One can easily inject more into the controller under test.